# SQL Server 2008 R2 : collect records with group by statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In Sql Server 2008R2, I need a script that will pull out memos attached to particular documents.  There can be multiple memos attached to any one doc. 
Do not need to concatenate memos, just have one record for each memo with the results grouped and separated by roid (repair order id)

```
select rd.id, rd.timestamp, rd.by_emp, rd.roid, ro.memo
from (repdoc rd IN(select rd.roid, count(*) as memo_count
from repdoc rd
group by rd.roid
having count(*) > 1)
```

Returns error 'near IN'

Also tried changing IN to a FROM statement with no better results.

```
sample data             
id          roid    timestamp   by_emp  memo
1458    698 date/time   14  needs brakes
1459    698 date/time   89  parts pulled
1460    698 date/time   32  parts installed
1521    698 date/time   32  tested
1200    145 date/time   14  picked up later
1201    1468    date/time   84  steering fluid needed
1203    1468    date/time   12  fluid installed


desired results             

roid    id  timestamp   by_emp  memo
698         1458    date/time   14  needs brakes
698         1459    date/time   89  parts pulled
698         1460    date/time   32  parts installed
698         1521    date/time   32  tested

1200    145 date/time   14  picked up later

1468    1201    date/time   84  steering fluid needed
1468    1203    date/time   12  fluid installed
```

tabs not lining up correctly, but I think you can see what is needed.

Thank you!!

Comment: Something like this: `select rd.id, rd.timestamp, rd.by_emp, rd.roid, ro.memo
from repdoc rd 
JOIN
(
  select roid
  from repdoc
  group by roid
  having count(*) > 1
) tmp on rd.roid = tmp.roid`

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  Since initial submission, I have had about six different requests stack up on me, It will be several hours before I can test everything.  That is why they call it Overflow I guess...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your query like

```
select rd.id, 
rd.timestamp, 
rd.by_emp, 
rd.roid, 
ro.memo,
xx.memo_count
from repdoc rd 
join (select roid, count(*) as memo_count
from repdoc
group by roid
having count(*) > 1) xx on rd.roid = xx.roid;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  After converting everything from Sample to actual, I am getting results, but not counts.. all counts coming back as 1.  Might be my conversion,.  Thank you again..